# VBA web scraping automating contents in HTML document without ID and classname

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping

I am trying to automate a process in which entry from a excel cell will be entered in to web form and resulting data will be collected in separated excel cell. However, the webpage HTML doesnt have class or ID. it is run through a jss script. Below is the HTML code -

[image]

I am stuck with following VBA code -

```
Sub updateSRV()

    Dim ie As InternetExplorer
    Dim doc As HTMLDocument
    
    Set ie = New InternetExplorer
    ie.Visible = True
    
    URL = "http://hwrapp:7778/reports/jsprep/umesh/cnote/cnote_query5.html"
    ie.navigate URL
    
    Do Until ie.Busy Or ie.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
        DoEvents
    Loop
    
    ie.document.getElementsByTagName$("input[name=cntno]").Value = 20220064

End Sub
```

Comment: I assume it's an intranet site still running in IE. Try the DOM method `getElementsByName()` as follows: `ie.document.getElementsByName("cntno")(0).Value = 20220064` If there is more than one element with the attribute `name="cntno"` and the desired one is not the first one, you have to specify the correct index instead of `(0)`.

Comment: yeah, it is a intranet site. I used the code given by you, it still isn't working.